# Greenplum: How to get key and value in row from json

Tags: sql, json, greenplum

My GP version is:
PostgreSQL 8.3.23 (Greenplum Database 5.18.0 build commit:6aec9959d367d46c6b4391eb9ffc82c735d20102) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 6.2.0, 64-bit compiled on Apr  3 2019 14:45:51

Sample data in json column
{"CHANNEL":"AUDIO"," COST TYPE":"Commissionable (COM)","COST TYPE SHORT":"Commissionable (COM)"}

I want keys and values in rows.
Expected output

| My_key | My_value |
| --- | --- |
| CHANNEL | AUDIO |
| COST TYPE | Commissionable (COM) |
| COST TYPE SHORT | Commissionable (COM) |

I have tried below sql but i get only keys in rows for values there is no function.
select  json_object_keys(custom_column_data::json)
from my_table;

Could any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the functions you need are `json_each` or `json_each_text`: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/admin_guide/query/topics/json-data.html#topic_z5d_snw_2z

Comment: I tried the above option but it did not get me the expected output.

Comment: Here is a working example with `json_each_text`: `SELECT json_data.key as my_key, json_data.value as my_value FROM my_table, json_each_text(my_table.custom_column_data) as json_data;` which returns

```
     my_key      |       my_value       
-----------------+----------------------
 CHANNEL         | AUDIO
  COST TYPE      | Commissionable (COM)
 COST TYPE SHORT | Commissionable (COM)
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me:

select json_object_keys(custom_column_data) as key ,
custom_column_data ->>json_object_keys(custom_column_data) as value
from my_table;